# How to end a forloop as soon as the nested if statement is true in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

**Intro-** I a object called application It has many attributes below is the model. One of the attribute is user. I want to see if request.user is in the objects user list

I have tried slice the `forloop` many ways in the template but have failed. I need only 1 result from the loop Either **"Do A"**  or **"Do B"** Depending on the the condition. Even if I have a million applications. but as soon as I get 3 applications Either I have 2  **"Do A"** or 2 **"Do B"**. `|slice:":1"` does not work unless I am using it wrong. Below is my code

```
{% for app in applications %} #applications is a Application.objects.all()
    {% if applicant.username in app.user.username %} #applicant is request.user The code checks if request.user is a part of objects.users list
        <p> Do A </p>
    {% else %}  
        <p> Do B </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

below are my models

```
class Application(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='verified')
    applied_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ... # Alot more fields
    token = models.CharField(max_length=350)
```

Comment: To me this reads as if you're doing "if the **string** username is in the **iterable** app.user.username which is a **string**" and that is always going to fail. Cause `samir` is not part of the list `['s', 'a', 'm', 'i', 'r']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing too much logic in your templates. Try this in your view instead (pseudocode since I don't know the structure of your view):

`applicants = Application.objects.all().values_list('user__username', flat=True)
context = {'is_applicant': request.user.username in applicants}`

And in your template:

```
if is_applicant:
    something
else:
    something else
```

Comment: When you say `Applicants.objects.all()` I believe you meant `Application.objects.all()` in which case in which case `request.user in Application.objects.all()` gives no result

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right. I've modified the answer to reflect your actual model structure.

Comment: This is a better code it ran the query only once as opposed to twice with my code

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the first element, you don't need a `for` loop. Simply use the value at index `0` (i.e. the first value):

```
{% if applicant.username in applications.0.user.username %}
    <p> Do A </p>
{% else %}  
    <p> Do B </p>
{% endif %}
```

For the record, there is no `break` statement in Django template languge.

Comment: the problem with that code is `app` is got from  `{% for app in applications %}`

Comment: `applicant` is `request.user` The code checks if `request.user` is a part of the `objects.user` list using `forloops` and the `if` statement I am sorry I have added that to the question as well

Comment: @SamirTendulkar Ah, right. The idea is the same though, see my updated answer.

Comment: This did not work It simply goes to the else clause Even if the user is in the list. `applications.0.user.username`  Doesn't this code just check the 1st user in the object list what if `request.user` is number 77th on the list

Comment: You have conflicting requirements. Your original question specified that you are only interested in the first result to see if it satisfies your condition. The above answer is a working version of the pseudo-code you wrote using `break` statements. Please clarify your question if this is not what you are after.

Comment: I wanted the code to check all the objects users to see if `request.user` is in that list and then stop. If I use a forloop it keeps iterating

Comment: I am sorry if the question was confusing I will try to edit it

Comment: You were right. Even if `{{ break  }}` existed my logic would still be wrong. I am sorry about that. I have tried again to explain the question

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it. Still testing this code It looks like it is working so far. I would love it if someone can better this code. As the loop runs even after the condition is met. the `|slice:":1"`  doesn't work

```
{% for app in applications %}  
    {% if applicant.username in app.user.username %} #drawback of this code the loop runs even after the condition is met. No way in Django template to stop that. See my 2nd answer the code is better but logic run in views
    <p> Do A </p>
    {% endif %}
{% empty %}
     <p> Do B <p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Note that `{% empty %}` is not a substitute for Python's `for..else` clause. It only runs when `applications` is empty or `None`. Your best bet is to move this code into your view and pass the result in a context variable.

Comment: @Selcuk Its a nightmare I tried it. The view is a create-view with a django form. Plus I have a get_context_data. to pass in `Application.objects.all` and `request.user`  I know this is not the best code. as the loop runs even after the condition is satisfied. Trying to figure how to stop that

Comment: You can write your own filter then, as the above code won't do what you need.

Comment: @Selcuk The above code does what I need but its not as efficient will try to achieve this in the view  as per your advise

Comment: The above code will only work for `Do A` but will never execute `Do B` unless `applications` list is empty.

Comment: @Selcuk The code goes to empty if the `if` statement is not met So it does. that is if `request.user` is not in objects user list the forloop is empty just like I want it the empty code then runs

Comment: Where does it say that? See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) It only runs the `empty` block if `applications` is empty. `if` has no relation to that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it in the views still have to check this for bugs though too late now will check tomorrow

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CreateApplication, self).get_context_data()
    context['applicant'] = self.request.user
    context['applications'] = Application.objects.all() #Application.objects.filter(is what I have used though)
    already_applied = None
    for app in Application.objects.all(): #Application.objects.filter(is what I have used though)
        if self.request.user.username in app.user.username:
            already_applied = self.request.user
            already_applied.save()
            print(already_applied)
            break
    context['already_applied'] = already_applied
    return context
```

Below is the template

```
{% if applicant == already_applied %}
    <p> Do A </p>
{% else %}
    <p> Do B </p> 
{% endif %}
```