# End a for loop if a certain condition is met in Django using templates

Tags: python, django

A similar question was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156605/how-to-end-a-forloop-as-soon-as-the-nested-if-statement-is-true-in-django-templa) but the provided solutions did not work for me.

Let's say I receive a list/queryset from the django views, for instance:

`views.py`:

```
requests = Request.objects.all() 
context['requests'] = requests
```

`models.py`:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=250, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        default=REQUEST_STATUS_DEFAULT,
        choices=REQUEST_STATUS,
    )
```

In the template:

```
{% for r in requests %}
    {% if r.status == "Active" %}
        //do A
    {% else %}
        //do B
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `requests` list has 10 elements, one of them satisfies the condition of `r.status == "Active"`. (invented example)

What I want is:

1. Check the `requests` list to determine if any of the elements in the list satisfies the condition of `r.status == "Active"` (or whatever condition, this is just an example)
2. If some element in the list has the status `Active` the for loop will execute only one iteration, run the `//do A` code and then the loop will finish/break.
3. If no element in the list has the status `Active`, the for loop will execute the `//do B` once and then break.

I'm a bit confused and I don't know if there is another default tag to do this type of operation in Django

Comment: Can you show how the requests context var is created? A for loop doesn't seem appropriate here, testing the for the condition first and then just having an if/else in the template should be simpler

Comment: The post you mentioned uses `{% empty %}` in one of the answers you can use that but as lain said it seems unnecessary please update the question with your view nobody is gonna steal your logic ;)

Comment: @IainShelvington I updated the question, is that enough info for you? Let me know if you need anything else, I am trying to make the code as much generic as possible in case it can be useful to someone in the future

Comment: @Ahtisham I updated my question with further details, thank you!

Comment: The post you mentioned is about doing the logic in the view rather than in the template. Could you explain why this does not work for you?